# Area of Trapezoid Does Not Equal Sum of Constituent Triangles

Tags: geometry

Trying to calculate the area of this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5hx6.png). It's two right triangles put together in the shape of a trapezoid. However, the sum of the areas of triangles doesn't equal the area of the trapezoid.

Sum of Area of Triangles:

$$((4*3) * 1/2) + ((12 * 5) * 1/2) = 36;$$

Area of Trapezoid:

$$(1/2 * (3 + 13))(4) = 32;$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observed, the two triangles are Pythagorean:  $\triangle ABD$ is $3$-$4$-$5$, and $\triangle BCD$ is $5$-$12$-$13$.

Now, suppose $ABCD$ is a trapezoid with $AB \parallel DC$ as the drawn figure seems to suggest.  Then if we were to draw the altitude from $DC$ to $B$, this would have length $AD = 4$.  If we call the foot of this altitude $E$, then $DE = AB = 5$ and $CE = CD - DE = 13 - 5 = 8$.  It would then follow that $\triangle BCE$ is right, with legs of length $4$ and $8$, and hypotenuse $12$.  But $4$-$8$-$12$ is not a Pythagorean triple since $4^2 + 8^2 = 80 \ne 144 = 12^2$.

An accurately drawn figure is shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure that's a trapezoid? The top and bottom look parallel in the picture, but is the picture a proof? Or is your calculation perhaps a proof that they aren't parallel?

Comment: It's not a proof. There are others in the same problem set where sides are parallel but not explicitly stated so.

Comment: It seems to me that, in your example, the top and bottom would not even be very close to parallel if the triangles were drawn accurately.

Comment: The fact that the areas don't add up is proof they are not parallel.  You can also calculate arctan 3/4 + arctan 12/5 and I'll bet they don't add to 90.

Comment: Actually, if it were a trapezoid, and you knew 3 and 4 you can calculate what the side marked 13 is.  I bet it's not 13.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

LET us consider the following angles

We see that in $triangle ABD...90+b+c=180$

We see that in $triangle CBD... 90+a+d=180$

then we can say $a+d=b+c$

IF THIS WAS TRAPEZIUM THEN $a$=$c$

WHICH IS ONLY POSSIBLE IF $d$=$b$

so if  $d$=$b$ we could have said it was a trapezium

but if  $d$ is not equal to n$b$ we cannot say it is a trapezium

***IN THE AFORESAID CASE IT IS NOT A TRAPEZIUM  which you can prove using trigonometry***

$cos(CDB)=\frac {5}{13}$, but $cos(ABD)=\frac {3}{5}$. Therefore those two lines are not parallel ie $a$ not equal to $c$

Answer (score 0):

$AB$ is not parallel to $DC$, because $cos(CDB)=\frac {5}{13}$, but $cos(ABD)=\frac {3}{5}$. Therefore those two lines are not parallel and the figure is not a trapezoid.